# How to impl LazyVerticalGrid with set full span or dynamic num of GridCells.Fixed in jetpack compose？

Tags: android, android-jetpack-compose

Just like `Sliver` in `Flutter` or `StaggeredGridLayoutManager` in android `reyclerview`

so I can insert a banner or some thing else into grid layout
[image]

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Both `item` and `items` have argument `span`, using which you can specify how many of grid placed each item takes:

```
val colors = listOf(
    Color.Gray,
    Color.Red,
    Color.Cyan,
    Color.Blue,
    Color.LightGray,
    Color.Yellow,
)
val columnsCount = 3
LazyVerticalGrid(columns = GridCells.Fixed(columnsCount)) {
    items(6) {
        Box(
            modifier = Modifier
                .height(100.dp)
                .fillMaxWidth()
                .background(colors[it])
        )
    }
    items(3, span = { GridItemSpan(columnsCount) }) {
        Box(
            modifier = Modifier
                .height(100.dp)
                .fillMaxWidth()
                .background(colors[it])
        )
    }
}
```

Result:

[image]

Comment: Thank you for your answer. I hope to randomly insert a banner (full width) into a grid(using the same set of list data). If I use lazycolumn (I see that lazyverticalgrid is also implemented using lazycolumn), I need to calculate the location of these different types of items by myself. It is not very simple. At present, it seems that I can only do so

Comment: and how to use it with pagingdata where everything happens dynamically?